# React JS Context, TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, posthog

I'm pretty new to JS and React JS so some help would be really appericated.

Im trying to create a context for this import 'posthogs'. I made a context file and I added the  and surrounded on of my main

**PostHogContext.js**

```
import posthog from "posthog-js";
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";

const PostHogContext  = React.createContext();

export function usePostHog(){
    return useContext(PostHogContext);
}

export default function PostHogContextProvider({ children }) {

    const [initPostHog,setInitPosthog] = useState(posthog)

    useEffect(() => {
            console.log("Initializing PostHog");
            setInitPosthog(posthog.init());
    },[initPostHog]);

    return(
        <PostHogContext.Provider value={initPostHog}>
            {children}
        </PostHogContext.Provider>
    )
}

export { PostHogContext };
```

Surrounded the context provider with main

```
<PostHogContextProvider>
  <Main>
</PostHogContextProvider>
```

When I call it in my from my **main.js**

```
function MainPage(props){

posthog.identify(user.email);

}
```

I get this error that says

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'identify')

from what I can see it doesn't seem like it found the posthog.identify function or the posthog value is null but i'm not sure why that is when I set it in the provider

Comment: Are you calling `usePostHog`?

Comment: @BenWest yes. I called I did ```const posthog = usePostHog()```

Comment: You are accessing the context ***outside*** the context provider and didn't provide any default context value, thus the undefined access.

Comment: @DrewReese what does this mean? Do I need to import posthog into my main.js?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I misread what the code was doing in the first snippet. Please edit question to include all relevant code. What is `Main` component doing, and what are the reproduction steps to induce the error?

Answer (score 1):

Okay I figured it out, first

my setState has a typo.

```
const [initPostHog,setInitPosthog] = useState(posthog)
```

initPostHog and setInitPosthog. So my value wasn't getting set correctly.